# Spaces in a string doesn't register as a space when trying to replaces occurrences of spaces

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating an app that uses Spotify's API of getting the currently playing song and using that info to get lyrics to the corresponding song but the name of the song I get from the lyric API has spaces that don't register as spaces when I try to replace occurrences of spaces.

Here is some example code that I used to check that

```
for(index, value) in songInfo.content.enumerated() {
    let potentialSongName = value.title.lowercased()
    print("Potential song name without spaces: \(potentialSongName.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: ""))")
    print("Song artist without spaces: \(songArtist.lowercased().replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: ""))")
    if potentialSongName.contains(songArtist.lowercased()) {
        print("song contains song artist")
    }
}
```

and here is an example of a result that I get

```
Potential song name without spaces: loseyoutolovemeby selena gomez
Song artist without spaces: selenagomez
```

It seems as what looks like spaces from the song name I get from the lyric API doesn't seem to be spaces after all. What could it be then?

Comment: It's possible they aren't "spaces", but simply "empty" or special characters

Comment: You could just do `potentialSongName.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)` you know...

Comment: @Sweeper this would not remove all white spaces, only those located at the string  suffix and prefix

Comment: `var songName = potentialSongName`
`songName.removeAll(where: \.isWhitespace)` Btw no need to lowercase it. You can use `localizedStandardContains` which is caseInsensitive.

Comment: To know what character it is, print its AXCII code. Could be an option-space (unsociable space).

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, I managed to do it a similar way to how you recommended it by potentialSongName.filer { !$0.isWhiteSpace }

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to use `localizedStandardContains` instead of lowercasing your strings.